# Need help deserializing a json object where one of the object name is a variabele

Tags: c#, json

So i have a json file where one of the object name is the id of the person. So for each person its a different id. So i dont know how to serialize it.

> {"19887289":[{"name":"Twisted Fate's Dragons","tier":"MASTER","queue":"RANKED_SOLO_5x5","entries":[{"playerOrTeamId":"19887289","playerOrTeamName":"Imaqtpie","division":"I","leaguePoints":237,"wins":72,"losses":37,"isHotStreak":false,"isVeteran":false,"isFreshBlood":true,"isInactive":false}]}]}

This is my json output.

And when i go to http://json2csharp.com/ and input it. It gives me a class name with __invalid_type__19887289

And this is what i have currently 
Dictionary< string, RootObject2 > root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject< Dictionary< string, RootObject2 >>(jsonrank);

Edit :::
Fixed the issue by using this :
[Deserialize JSON into C# dynamic object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object)

Still curious how to solve my problem tho.

Comment: What IS `Rootobject2`? Show its definition

Comment: @HimBromBeere Its just the main object. All it contains is a list with a object that is my json output. You can get a better answer by going to json2csharp.com and pasitng my json output into it

Comment: `Dictionary< string, RootObject2 >` is the best solution, since your JSON is basically a dictionary of objects keyed by an ID.  I suppose you could use `Dictionary< long, RootObject2 >` if you are sure the id is always numeric.  Or perhaps something more descriptive than `RootObject2`, maybe `GameObject` or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to deserialize to a dictionary

```
var players = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Player>>(json);



public class Entry
{
    public string playerOrTeamId { get; set; }
    public string playerOrTeamName { get; set; }
    public string division { get; set; }
    public int leaguePoints { get; set; }
    public int wins { get; set; }
    public int losses { get; set; }
    public bool isHotStreak { get; set; }
    public bool isVeteran { get; set; }
    public bool isFreshBlood { get; set; }
    public bool isInactive { get; set; }
}

public class Player
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string tier { get; set; }
    public string queue { get; set; }
    public List<Entry> entries { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can override the JSON property name of your model when being serialized or deserialized using Newtonsoft.Json

```
[JsonProperty("integer")]
public string Number {get;set;}
```

When you serialize your model, instead of "Number" you'll see "integer" as property name. Also, if you want to deserialize a JSON string, the "integer" property will be your "Number".

Comment: I might be explain this wrong. The object name is a variabele. So for each request it changes. So i cant really create objects for them because they dont know have name only a value that is constantly different.